# When gets this static variable initalised and when to use StringBuffer

Tags: java

I just saw this example

```
public class Runtime {
    //When is this private member initalised ??
    private static Runtime currentRuntime = new Runtime();


    public static Runtime getRuntime() {
        return currentRuntime;
    }
```

Now when you call Runtime.getRuntime() currentRuntime is already initalised even an instance of this class was never created. How does it work ?

My second question is about StringBuffer ?

```
String var = "Hello World";
```

Now if you do `var = var + "!";`

Whould it be better to use a StringBuffer. I mean StringBuffer reserves a lot of memory I think 1000Byte at least, so just for that simple example it would still be better no to use StringBuffer. Of course
now we have 2 Strings in memory "Hello World" and "Hello World!"  but still better than StringBuffer with 1000 Byte or more . Right ?

Comment: Please [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this: "when gets this static variable initialized"

I've experienced that Java classes are loaded when they're needed. For example, if you never use it (for example, you never refer to a variable, or call a function/constructor) the JVM does not initialize the class.

So, when you call Runtime.getRuntime(), then the class is initialized and so are the static fields.

You can also test it using static blocks with this code

```java
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("program starts");
        Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("programs end");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Runtime {
    //When is this private member initalised ??
    private static Runtime currentRuntime = new Runtime();

    static {
        System.out.println("when this is called the class is beeing initialized");
        System.out.println("is currentRuntime null? -> " + (currentRuntime == null));
    }

    public static Runtime getRuntime() {
        System.out.println("getRuntime is executed");
        return currentRuntime;
    }
}
```

This is what i get on the console

```
program starts
when this is called the class is beeing initialized
is currentRuntime null? -> false
getRuntime is called
programs end
```

What does this mean? That the class Runtime (and its fields) are **not** initialized before main() starts, but it is initialized when Runtime **is requested**.

Also, the static block is called when *currentRuntime* is not null, so it's already initialized (remember that Java is top-down).

So, it's initialized when Runtime.getRuntime() is called, but before it's executed